# Canny edge detection C++ is showing error?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface, native

I'm a complete beginner in both `native c++` and `opencv` so please excuse me if my question is foolish.Basically I'm passing the bitmap to the `native C++` for *canny edge detection* by using `opencv` but the problem is it's showing error. My procedure of doing this might be wrong. So, can anyone please help me to fix this issue ?

Code Java:

```
Bitmap new_bitmap=bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);

            int[] pixels = new int[bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight()];

            //Converting bitmap to byteArray
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            new_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] FrameData = stream.toByteArray();
            //bitmap.recycle();

            ImageProcessing(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), FrameData, pixels);
            new_bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
            imgView.setImageBitmap(new_bitmap);
```

Code native C++:

```
#include <jni.h>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

  Mat * mCanny = NULL;

  extern "C"
  jboolean
  Java_opengl_community_testopencv_MainActivity_ImageProcessing(
    JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz,
    jint width, jint height,
    jbyteArray NV21FrameData, jintArray outPixels)
 {
jbyte * pNV21FrameData = env->GetByteArrayElements(NV21FrameData, 0);
jint * poutPixels = env->GetIntArrayElements(outPixels, 0);

if ( mCanny == NULL )
{
    mCanny = new Mat(height, width, CV_8UC1);
}

Mat mGray(height, width, CV_8UC1, (unsigned char *)pNV21FrameData);
Mat mResult(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char *)poutPixels);
IplImage srcImg = mGray;
IplImage CannyImg = *mCanny;
IplImage ResultImg = mResult;

 cvCanny(&srcImg, &CannyImg, 80, 100, 3);
 //cvSmooth(&srcImg,&CannyImg,3,0,0,0);
 cvCvtColor(&CannyImg, &ResultImg, CV_GRAY2BGRA);
//cvCvtColor(&srcImg, &CannyImg, CV_BGR2GRAY);

env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(NV21FrameData, pNV21FrameData, 0);
env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(outPixels, poutPixels, 0);
return true;
}
```

Error:

```
11-19 23:12:30.264 2645-2645/opengl.community.testopencv E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
```

Comment: `IplImage ` why arent you using `Mat` instead? Also `IplImage CannyImg = *mCanny`, you might want to use `Mat CannyImg=mCanny.clone()`.

Comment: @macroland sir thanks for your answer but I've got this code from some website so could you please elaborate what to change in detail

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d5b/structIplImage.html

Comment: @macroland sir I tried your **Mat** technique but it didn't work

Comment: Did you debug to see if height and width and other parameters are sound?

Comment: @macroland yes sir width is 640 and height is 480